# RECOVERY MODEL changed on a database, no record in Default Trace

Tags: sql-server, trace, recovery-model

I have a Log backup job running every hour via SQL Agent. This morning it failed at 3:00 AM with this error:

The statement BACKUP LOG is not allowed while the recovery model is SIMPLE.

But it ran fine at 2:00 AM. So sometime between 2 and 3, it went from FULL to SIMPLE.
My response was:

1. Change it back to FULL recovery
2. Run a FULL DATABASE BACKUP
3. Run the Log Backup job to make sure it would still work.
   All good, no data loss.

So I got to investigating the Default Trace for events about possibly WHO might have made the change between 2 and 3. I first identified the event on Step #1 above so I knew what types of events I was looking for. Unfortunately, there is no event to say, "The recovery model changed from x to y". All it has is "Object: Altered" for my login for the database in question, with rows for BEGIN and COMMIT.

Here's the issue: I found NOTHING in the default trace in the time span to indicate that anyone made a change to this database.

Question: How could this change have occurred and it NOT get recorded in the Default Trace? It certainly recorded the fact that I changed it back. Why not the first change?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Todd this is obvious but still checking any chance your default trace duration rolled over and passed the time when the database recovery model was changed?

Comment: Yes, to expound on my findings. This was an Azure SQL VM and as such the Automated Patching window took advantage and patched the SQL instance. Looking at the SQL logs, I think the default trace was stopped along the way somewhere, which is why this was not captured in that tool. But I DID see the change explicitly in the SQL Logs. Which makes me wonder if there is a bug in the SQL patching that does this and then NOT return msdb back to FULL as it found it.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own post as I found additional information:

The trace log had no indication of Object: Altered for that database, which happened to be msdb (might be important here). In the SQL logs, I found indications that someone had applied updates, and after the first instance start-up, there was indication that msdb had an upgrade script applied then setting of SIMPLE recovery, along with creation of several synonyms.